# Using setuid in Ubuntu to exec Java from C

Tags: java, ubuntu, path, root, setuid

I am running Ubuntu 11.04.

I am trying to use a "C" execlp program to run a Java program, and then  I want to setuid on the "C" program so the Java program can execute as root.  There is an example of this here:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/110254/Linux-UNIX/setuid

I followed the example to the letter except instead of being the tomcat user, I used root.

Root is able to execute the "C" program which in turn executes the Java program.  And, before giving root ownership, the User (me) can run the "C" program which executes the Java program.  But once I setup to use setuid, and the User tries to execute the program. I get what seems to be an LD_LIBRARY_PATH type of error:
**java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

The libjli.so file exists under the Java JRE.  Both the User and Root can see this file when they run individually.  But the User cannot see it when he runs the program after setuid to root has taken place.

Is there some different way that root's LD_LIBRARY_PATH gets set when a setuid program executes?  Is this an interactive vs. non-interactive problem?

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As the `LD_*` environment variables can be used to load code into a process, they are all ignored by setuid binaries. You will probably need to make the setuid binary a wrapper which executes the C program.

Comment: Right now I have a C program wrapping a Java program.  Are you suggesting I use a script to wrap the C program that wraps the Java program?  Or did you mean something else?  I am willing to try whatever it takes.  Please expound.  Thanks.

Comment: Yep -- either a script or another C program, which sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` appropriately and `exec()`s the C program.

Comment: I don't think this would work.  The linker detects the setuid bit from the EUID and RUID of the process, which is preserved across `exec`.

Comment: I tried it with a bash script, and I could not get it to work.  I will try it with a C program and get back.  Dietrich is probably correct, but I will try most anything now.

Comment: Using setreuid(0,0) in the C program that calls the Java program did fix the immediate problem.  Of course, I did have to setuid on the C program itself as was mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the setuid bit on a file will change the process's effective UID but not the real UID.  The dynamic linker will check to see if EUID ≠ RUID, and if so, it will ignore all environment variables.  Your wrapper will have to filter the environment variables itself (important!) and once done, change the real UID to match the effective UID.

**Warning:** Don't forget to scrub the environment variables well, unless you are okay with giving everyone on the box full root access.

Comment: I may have put my previous comments in the wrong box.  By scrubbing environment variables, do you mean that I should somehow only present just a minimum and necessary set of environment variables before "exec"ing the Java program from the "C" wrapper?

Comment: More than than that.  You must also check that the environment variables have permitted values.  If all you need is ICMP pings, then you are going about this backwards — try putting the ping capability in a C program and have that program run as root.  This would be more secure and less complicated.

Answer (score 0):

To work around the `LD_*` environment constraints on setuid programs, on most POSIX systems you should be able to do this within your wrapper code:

```
setreuid(0, 0);
```

which will set both the real *and* effective UIDs to be `root`, although this will only work if the program itself was started with the `setuid` bit enabled.

I wouldn't do it, though.

Look at why your Java program needs to run as root, and see if there are better ways to give it the privileges it needs without actually running as root.

Comment: My requirements are for the Java program to perform an icmp ping without using an OS command (i.e. I cannot use /usr/bin/ping).  The InetAddress class in Java performs an icmp ping in the isReachable method, but only if run as root.

Comment: I forgot to add this.  I am a bit concerned about the admonition to:

Comment: Sorry, it seems like hitting return sends my comment prematurely.  I am worried about "scrubbing the environment variables".  This sounds like it could lead to another topic because I am not smart enough to understand yet what this means.  Could you point me to something I can read about this topic, and thanks very much for the help I received.